# Use derived (median, mean) for domainMid

Tags: vega-lite

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bubbleplot showing horsepower on x, miles per gallons on y, and weight with a diverging color scale.",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "Weight_in_lbs",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domainMid": 3250, "range": "diverging"}
    }
  }
}
```

See the example obtained from https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#domain.
I would like to use median value for domainMid instead of hard coded 3250. This is needed especially on Trellis plot (facet) where I would like each chart to compute and use its median for its domainMid.

Is there anyway to achieve this with Vega-Lite? Maybe with the use of Aggregate?

EDIT:
https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8020
Created a feature enhancement issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can access the full data using expression "data(name)" then define a custom vega expression that finds out the median for the given data.

So for the spec below, you will need to provide a custom median function that takes array of data and field to compute the median value for.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bubbleplot showing horsepower on x, miles per gallons on y, and weight with a diverging color scale.",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json", "name": "source"},
  "mark": "point",
  "transform": [
      {
        "joinaggregate": [{
            "op": "median",
            "field": "Weight_in_lbs",
            "as": "medianWeight"
        }]
      }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "Weight_in_lbs",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domainMid": { "expr": "median(data('source'), "Weight_in_lbs")" }, "range": "diverging"}
    }
  }
}
```

However, since data returns all data, it still won't work for Trellis Plot